# SSIS multicast cause issue

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package. which read data from OLEDB source and write to flat file on a server folder.
Recently I made changes to use add multicast between OLEDB source and flat file connection.
One output is for existing flat file and other output is for a new flat file manager which store same data on different server.

First flat file was "UTF-8" encoded and second flat file was "ANSI" due to this faced problem that when source data had special characters (non English) then generated file had partial data.

This is happening for "Flat file 2" which I can understand is due to "ANSI" encoding.

But intermittently this is also happening for "Flat file 1" which is "UTF-8".

Facing this issue in "QA" environment. In "DEV" environment issue is only with "Flat file 2".

Couldn't understand why "QA" environment has issue with "flat file 1"

Comment: Is the type of data that is tested successfully in DEV for flat file 1 same as in QA? Assuming there are 10 rows with non-unicode records in DEV, does your QA data too have about 10 such rows?

Comment: yes data is same. Another thing I have noticed is that after we changed "Flat file 2" encoding to "UTF-8". Everything is working fine in both DEV and QA. Was "Flat file 2" encoding taking precedence and getting applied on "Flat file 1" intermittently. is this possible?

Comment: Nope Flat File Destination transforms are unique entities and settings do not get carried forward or have any precedense set. Does having both set to UTF-8 do the job?

Comment: Yes after setting both to UTF-8 it worked. not sure why it was failing in first place.